# WCF <ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty.</ExceptionString>

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I write the WCF services and hosted it on windows service (Self host) and expose `method1` and `method2`. From this method 1 is working properly but  when i am trying to consume `method2` it is giving me error like

`An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://********/*******/service. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.`

When I check the app_tracelog so in **XML** there is
`System.Xml.XmlException: The body of the message cannot be read because it is empty`.

So can anyone please tell why this is happening? It is working for one method and not working for other method.

Comment: show your services code.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934209/wcf-service-returning-400-error-the-body-of-the-message-cannot-be-read-because

Comment: @ Amit i tried all the things in above theaad but still problem persist.

Comment: show some of your service code.