# WCF http binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I create a wcf service application and a asp.net mvc project(as client). I added my wcf service via Add Service Reference file to my asp.net mvc reference. I use Entity Framework to connect DB in my wcf application. I have a `UserManagement.svc.cs` service. 
This is my `UserManagement.svc.cs` codes:

```
 public class UserManagement : IUserManagement
{
    iFlowEntities db = new iFlowEntities();

    public void AddRole(role role)
    {
        db.roles.Add(role);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public List<role> RoleList()
    {
        List<role> roles;
        roles =  db.roles.ToList();
        return roles;
    }

}
```

And I use this service in my `UserController` in RoleList() action in asp.net mvc and this is that action code:

```
    public ActionResult RoleList()
    {
        IList<UserManagement.role> roles = new List<UserManagement.role>();
        roles = UserClient.RoleList();
        return View("_RoleList",roles);
    }
```

and UserClient variable define in controller body like:  `UserManagement.UserManagementClient UserClient = new UserManagement.UserManagementClient();`

When I run asp.net project I get this error:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://localhost:1730/UserManagement.svc. This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down).

I googled and see multiple answer and test them but don't have result for me and this answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870958/this-could-be-due-to-the-service-endpoint-binding-not-using-the-http-protocol) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/686499d2-5e31-47ee-941b-760264472875/an-error-occurred-while-receiving-the-http-response-to-xxx-problem-wcf-comunication?forum=wcf) and [this](https://daivagnananavati.blogspot.com/2012/09/an-error-occurred-while-receiving-http.html?showComment=1470755188584).

And this is my wcf service config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="262144" executionTimeout="103600" targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="iFlowEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.DBContext.csdl|res://*/Model.DBContext.ssdl|res://*/Model.DBContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=iFlow;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Edited:**

Yes, I add `DataContract` and `DataMember` to my class and `ServiceContract` and `OperationContract`.

This is my client config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserManagement" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDepartmentManagement" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1730/UserManagement.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IUserManagement"
        contract="UserManagement.IUserManagement" name="BasicHttpBinding_IUserManagement" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:1730/DepartmentManagement.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDepartmentManagement"
        contract="DepartmentManagement.IDepartmentManagement" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDepartmentManagement" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why did you add the WCF service directly to your ASP.NET application?  That's not how web services work.  You should add it via Add Service Reference.

Comment: I added service reference to reference of my asp.net mvc. I edited this quetion.

Comment: Mr @jon-skeet please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You're setting your service to use https (<add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />) and you're trying to call using http. If you don't intend to use https, remove the scheme="https". Also, add <security mode="None" />. Also, change this line: <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />

Comment: Mr @Ricardo Pontual I tested it but don't any result.

Comment: How did you define role class? Have you added DataContract to it? To get exact error, I suggest you to use [Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: When I add tracing enable to my wcf project config file I get internal server error when I want update my references.

Comment: @Farshid Is there any detailed error message? Could you broswer your service from IE?

Comment: I can access from url like http://localhost:1730/UserManagement.svc.

Comment: how I can find out m problem in file trace log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue is an `Entity Framework` matter. Whenever you serialize an entity in WCF service, it tries to load child entities as well, while WCF can't serialize them. To solve this issue simply disable `Proxy Creation` option in DbContext constructor:

```
public class DatabaseEntities : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseEntities()
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
}
```